# What is a good approach to handle image uploads in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, resize-image, multi-upload

This is a codeigniter based project and I'm not sure if this question is just redundant to other questions here regarding image upload that i've done reading about but i feel like i have to ask this anyway (you are free to downvote if you like).

I'm using http://code.google.com/p/ax-jquery-multiuploader/ plugin and I also incorporate ResizeImage library, it works just fine except the thumb which i guess having issues related to server's max memory script. My site is hosted in a shared server so i have limitation in terms of changing server settings. My users upload pretty large images some even reach an MB in size.

Now, what i just want to know is, if is there a way to optimize an image before it reaches to my "upload script" (i mean of course programatically, i should not be asking the user to upload only this size because it's pretty inconvenient in their part), i want to make sure that the image to be uploaded is readily reduced in size before i will save it to the server?

I welcome any thoughts..  help appreciated

Comment: List the questions you've been worked through. Excerpt them, tell how they helped and what you keep missing.

Comment: oh yeah sorry if this sounds really confusing because i honestly confused anyway.. let me put it this way, how can i resize the image before it lands to the server, maybe some sort of smush.it functionality and then save it to the server.  I did pretty well with Resize image once they get saved to the server but this is okay if smaller in size the large one will hang up.

Comment: I have understood that part (after I finally went to the end of your question), however you wrote earlier that you smeel redundancy to existing questions you have reviewed. List those, tell us why what was suggested there didn't made it for you, tell us what you're missing, what you want to know about additionally. But link those other questions.

Comment: ah yeah, because i actually have observed the same behavior as what described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491443/php-jquery-uploader-by-albanx-blank-page but in my case i figured out the cause and it's due to memory_limit = 128M which is not enough, my problem is I can't change this in a shared hosting so I was hoping that maybe without changing anything to the setting there's a way to reduced the image on the fly.. (and it's tougher than i thought :D)

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks,

I finally found a good tool https://github.com/whizzzkid/phpimageresize very helpful. I don't need to resize images from the server. This can resize images on the fly.